# How to solve the problem vertex conflict in NebulaGraph Database?

Tags: nebula-graph

When I update some vertices with NebulaGraph, it gives the hint "vertex conflict".
Want to know why? I checked every operation and find nothing.

I checked every step and operation during the process.
Hope to know why this hint is given and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please provide enough information about how to reproduce this issue? (i.e. a [mre])

Answer (score 0):

This happens when two threads are writing on the same vertex. Just retry.

https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/20.appendix/0.FAQ/#how_to_resolve_the_error_edge_conflict_or_vertex_conflict